# Use an SSH Tunnel to access a webapp on a phone through a middle-man

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

tl;dr:  A -> B and C -> B works. How to get A->C to work?

I have 3 hosts

```
A. A local machine
B. A middle-man
C. A phone with a webapp running on port 333
```

Both A and C can SSH into B. So,  A->B  and C->B works fine but A -> C does not work.

On B, I can access this webapp at `http://localhost:3344` after creating a tunnel from C:

```
machine-c$ /usr/bin/ssh -f -N -T -R 3344:localhost:333 user@machine-b
```

I would have thought that with the above tunnel working all I need is a tunnel from A->B like so:

```
machine-a$ /usr/bin/ssh -f -N -T -L 9999:machine-b:3344 user@machine-b
```

I can see the following message:

```
Local connections to LOCALHOST:9999 forwarded to remote address machine-b:3344
```

But accessing localhost:9999 hangs with the following set of messages being repeated:

```
debug2: channel 3: zombie
debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9999 for machine-b port 3344, connect from ::1 port 24626 to ::1 port 9999, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 9999 forwarding to machine-b port 3344 requested.
debug2: fd 10 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Operation timed out
```

---

Am not sure whether it's relevant, but since A -> B works, I have also setup a reverse tunnel so that B -> A works too.  Ditto for B-> C.  So overall the following works:

A -> B

```
machine-a$  ssh user@machine-b
```

B -> A (first requires a reverse SSH Tunnel from A->B)

```
machine-a$  ssh -f -N -T user@machine-b -R1234:localhost:22
machine-b$  ssh -p 1234 user@machine-a
```

The same has been done for C->B

---

How can I setup an SSH tunnel from A to C (through B?) so that I can access that webapp directly on A using localhost:3344 ?

I have looked at the following questions but can't wrap my head around what's needed:

[SSH as socks proxy through multiple hosts](https://superuser.com/questions/332850/ssh-as-socks-proxy-through-multiple-hosts)

[Forward SSH traffic through a middle machine](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine)

[An SSH tunnel via multiple hops](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops)

Comment: If what you are saying is correct Station B has network access to the web application on Station C. You also stated that you are able to successfully able to access Station B from Station A via SSH. What happens when you try to access the web application hosted on Station C when you initiate a SSH connection to Station B from Station A?

Comment: I have updated my question with the details of what happens. Please take a look.

Comment: Try creating a Dynamic proxy going from A -> B and in the same session from B -> C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similiar setup in place and it is working fine. The difference I spotted is, in your machine-a ssh command you are using `9999:machine-b:3344` while I use `9999:localhost:3344`. Your way doesn't work for me either, however it doesn't produce the same errors. For completeness, this is what I get:

```
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 9999.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.5p1 Debian-6
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`
```

---

The following commands do the trick for me:

```
machine-c$  ssh -f -N -T -R 3344:localhost:333 user@machine-b
```

Now on machine-a:

```
machine-a$  ssh -f -N -T -L 9999:localhost:3344 user@machine-b
```

As I don't have anything running on machine-c's port 333, I substituted it for 22 and check that the tunnel is working by simply connecting through ssh:

```
machine-a$  ssh -p 9999 user@localhost
```

Comment: Wow! That totally works for me !!!!! Thanks a lot!

Would you know why 9999:localhost:3344 works but 9999:machine-b:3344 does not ?

Comment: Well, localhost address on machine-b and machine-b address are two different things. The first command (from machine-c) makes the ssh daemon on machine-b listen on 127.0.0.1::3344, but **not** on other adresses that machine-b has. The loopback interface is like another network device. So you were attempting to connect to the correct port, but on another network device.